# Cesium handling Multiple polygons with callback

Tags: javascript, php, cesiumjs

i draw 2 polygons using callback method

Consider i have 2 polygons ABC and DEF a. When i dragin corners of ABC polygon it works perfectly. when i drag second polygon i-e i draged DEF then ABC disappers and DEF is there.

if i have 3 polyons when i drag corners of 3rd polygon first and second polygons both disappers.

here is sandcastle code [click me](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

can someone guide me what's am i doing wronge here is my code ....

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
var scene = viewer.scene;

var polygonCollection = [];
var Poly_pointsCollections = [];

var Poly_coordiantesArray = [
    [72.35433701166211, 52.57522385967319, 96.18442795152974, 44.89719893727921, 72.39011732046649,
        39.86453159141635
    ],
    [67.29773654341213, 32.88259716109294, 69.14234015976554, 32.98282610463128, 69.19404079866142,
        31.354623867578226, 66.85127436871454, 31.712787322338162, 66.55451189733644, 32.6854597580088
    ]
];
var Poly_nameArray = ["aaaaa", "bbbbb"];

var loadedPolyCollection = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    loadPoly(Poly_coordiantesArray[i], Poly_nameArray[i]);
}

var selectionPolygonPoints = [];


var loadedPoly;

function loadPoly(coordinate, myArray) {

    loadedPoly = viewer.entities.add({
        id: "poly_" + myArray,
        name: myArray,
        polygon: {

            hierarchy: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function() {
                    return {
                        positions: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(coordinate)
                    }
                },
                false),

            material: Cesium.Color.fromBytes(221, 240, 235, 160),
        }


    });
    console.log(loadedPoly);
    console.log(loadedPolyCollection);
    loadedPolyCollection.push(loadedPoly);

    console.log("loadedPoly ", loadedPoly);


    for (var i = 0; i < coordinate.length; i = i + 2) {
        draw_Zone_Corner_points(coordinate[i], coordinate[i + 1], myArray);
    }

    viewer.flyTo(loadedPoly);


}



function draw_Zone_Corner_points(lon, lat, name) {

    var pointGeometry = viewer.entities.add({
        name: "Polypoint_" + name,
        description: [lon, lat],
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat),
        point: {
            color: Cesium.Color.SKYBLUE,
            pixelSize: 10,
            outlineColor: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
            outlineWidth: 3,
            disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, // we can see points arounds earth
            //heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
        },
    });
    Poly_pointsCollections.push(pointGeometry);
}
var selectedPolygonCoordinates = [];

function newArrayForZone(pickedEntity) {

    selectedPolygonCoordinates = [];
    var selected_Entity_Name = pickedEntity.id._name;
    for (var i = 0; i < Poly_pointsCollections.length; i++) {
        var current_Entity_Name = Poly_pointsCollections[i]._name;

        if (current_Entity_Name == selected_Entity_Name) {
            var [y, x] = Poly_pointsCollections[i]._description._value;
            selectedPolygonCoordinates.push(y, x);
        }
    }

}




function UpdatepolygonWithPoints(pickedEntity) {

    var Newpoints = pickedEntity.id.position._value;
    var carto = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(Newpoints);
    var lon = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(carto.longitude);
    var lat = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(carto.latitude);

    var [y, x] = pickedEntity.id._description._value;

    for (var i = 0; i < Poly_pointsCollections.length; i++) {
        if (selectedPolygonCoordinates[i] === y) {
            selectedPolygonCoordinates[i] = lon;
        }
        if (selectedPolygonCoordinates[i] === x) {
            selectedPolygonCoordinates[i] = lat;
        }
    }
    pickedEntity.id._description._value = [lon, lat];


    var entityName = pickedEntity.id._name;
    entityName = entityName.split("_");

    for (i = 0; i < loadedPolyCollection.length; i++) {

        if (entityName[1] == loadedPolyCollection[i]._name) {

            var poly_entity = loadedPolyCollection[i];
            console.log("this.loadedPolyCollection[i] ", loadedPolyCollection[i]);
            poly_entity._polygon._hierarchy = new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function() {
                return new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(
                    selectedPolygonCoordinates));
            }, false);

        }

    }

}

var ZoneMoment = true;
// Points_DragAndDrop
document.getElementById("cesiumContainer").addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (ZoneMoment) {

        var rightEntityPicked = false;
        var dragging = false;
        var pickedEntity;
        var mouseDroped = false;
        var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);
        handler.setInputAction(
            function(click) {
                if (ZoneMoment) {
                    console.log('LEFT down ');
                    var pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
                    if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject) && pickedObject.id) {
                        var entityName = pickedObject.id._name;
                        entityName = entityName.split("_");
                        if (entityName[0] === 'Polypoint') {
                            rightEntityPicked = true;
                        }
                        if (rightEntityPicked) {
                            dragging = true;
                            scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate = false;
                            pickedEntity = pickedObject;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_DOWN
        );
        handler.setInputAction(
            function(movement) {
                if (ZoneMoment && dragging) {
                    var cartesian = pickedEntity.id.position.getValue(Cesium.JulianDate
                        .fromDate(
                            new Date()));
                    var cartographic = scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(cartesian);
                    var surfaceNormal = scene.globe.ellipsoid.geodeticSurfaceNormal(cartesian);
                    var planeNormal = Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(scene.camera.position,
                        cartesian,
                        new Cesium
                        .Cartesian3());
                    planeNormal = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(planeNormal, planeNormal);
                    var ray = viewer.scene.camera.getPickRay(movement.endPosition);
                    var plane = Cesium.Plane.fromPointNormal(cartesian, planeNormal);
                    var newCartesian = Cesium.IntersectionTests.rayPlane(ray, plane);
                    var newCartographic = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(
                        newCartesian);
                    cartographic.longitude = newCartographic.longitude;
                    cartographic.latitude = newCartographic.latitude;
                    pickedEntity.id.position.setValue(scene.globe.ellipsoid
                        .cartographicToCartesian(
                            cartographic));

                }
                if (dragging) {
                    mouseDroped = true;
                }
            },
            Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE
        );
        handler.setInputAction(
            function() {
                if (ZoneMoment && rightEntityPicked && mouseDroped) {
                    console.log('Left up ');
                    dragging = false;
                    mouseDroped = false;
                    scene.screenSpaceCameraController.enableRotate = true;

                    newArrayForZone(pickedEntity);
                    UpdatepolygonWithPoints(pickedEntity);
                }

            },
            Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_UP
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. for time being I did a long method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still looking for a better answer. for time being I did a long method.

1. initially when polygon are drawn I changed it to Static polygon.
2. On right clicked I get that entity and deleted that and recreate a dynamic polygon same as static but using callback. **note** I don't allow multiple polygon to edit at once
3. you can play with dynamic polygon after that user saves the polygon and it converts back to static.
4. Now user can click on some other polygon and repeat step 1.